# CI and Angular4 : Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, php, angular, codeigniter

i have load all of these on my backend (CI) and i placed it on the construct :

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if($method == "OPTIONS") {
        die();
    }
```

but i still have this error :

> Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

is this problem come from the backend (CI) or my front-end (Angular4) ?

Comment: If you are using chrome you can use CORS plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en 
But as Akshay has said below you should add the headers from backend if you need a permanent fix.

Comment: i have already add 'header `(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`,`header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');`, and `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");`  are those not enough ?

Comment: why are you calling die() method for the preflight request ?  Try removing it.

Comment: @AhmedShabib `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405` still ihave the same issue

Comment: Try adding following header 
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header in the response from backend just like you have done for request

Answer (score 0):

Try use Chrome Extension CORS.

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog
```